# Custom cell not getting height returned by heightforrowatindexpath

Tags: ios, objective-c

I'm trying to have dynamic cell heights. I've created a custom cell programmatically. Now I want the cell to change in height, but it seems to always be returning `44` which is the default tableviewcell height. Why is this?

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];
    [self.reminderTableView registerClass:[ReminderTableViewCell class] forCellReuseIdentifier:@"Daybreak-Cell"];
}


- (CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath*)indexPath;
{
    if (indexPath.row > 3) {
        return 60;
    }
    return 70;
}

- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

    CustomCell *cell = (CustomCell *)[tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"Custom-Cell" forIndexPath:indexPath];

    ...
    return cell;
 }
```

**Custom Cell**

```
@implementation CustomCell

- (id)initWithStyle:(UITableViewCellStyle)style reuseIdentifier:(NSString *)reuseIdentifier
{
    self = [super initWithStyle:style reuseIdentifier:reuseIdentifier];
    if (self) {
        NSLog(@"HEIGHT: %f",self.frame.size.height);
        // Initialization code
        [self.contentView setFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, [[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds].size.width, kDefaultTableViewCellHeight)];
        [self setBackgroundColor:[UIColor clearColor]];
        [self createViews];
    }
    return self;
}
```

Comment: you are logging the height in the init? The cell is reused..so the height change also after the allocation..doesn't make sense log there the height. How do you know is returning 44? your code seems correct. Even if there is no correlation between CustomCell and the cell you are registering for reusing.

Comment: I just tested it and confirmed that `heightForRowAtIndexPath` is called _after_ `initWithStyle`.

Comment: check the height in your cellForRowAtIndexPath method. See what happens if you change it there before you return it

Comment: You seem to be registering Daybreak-cell for reuse but creating cells of type Custom-Cell? Also have you made sure you set the `dataSource` AND the `delegate` for the table to `self`` if not using a UITableViewController?

Answer (score 0):

All you need to do, starting with iOS7 i believe, is:

```
self.tableView.estimatedRowHeight = 100.0;
self.tableView.rowHeight = UITableViewAutomaticDimension;
```

to get the cell to be of a dynamic height, also don't forget to put constraints within your cell from top to the bottom

Comment: iOS8 is when automatic cell sizing comes in. In iOS7 you have to set the height in the delegate.

Answer (score 0):

JUST ensure that you are setting your table's delegate to be the class containing

```
- (CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath*)indexPath;
{
    if (indexPath.row > 3) {
        return 60;
    }
    return 70;
}
```

As this method works with me